# About the completeness of a normed space

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $K$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}^n$, with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Suppose that $K$ is symmetric ($K(A\times C\times B)=K(B\times C\times A)$) and positive definite ($\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^n} f(x,t)f(y,t)K(dx,dt,dy)\geq0$ for each bounded measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,T]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$).

Define the norm $\|f\|$ of a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,T]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as 
$$ \|f\|^2=\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x,t)f(y,t)|K(dx,dt,dy).$$
Let $P$ be the space of such functions with finite norm. I want to prove that **$P$ is complete**.

First, given any $f$, consider $B=\{(x,s)\in\mathbb{R}^n \times[0,T]:|f(x,s)|\geq\epsilon\}$, $\epsilon>0$. Then
$$\epsilon K(B\times\mathbb{R}^n)\leq \|f\| (K(B\times\mathbb{R}^n))^{1/2}.$$ This is easily proved as follows:
$$ \epsilon K(B\times\mathbb{R}^n)=\iiint_{B\times\mathbb{R}^n}\epsilon K(dx,dt,dy)\leq (f,1_{B\times\mathbb{R}^n})_K\leq \|f\| (K(B\times\mathbb{R}^n))^{1/2}, $$
where Cauchy-Schwarz inequality has been applied.

Let $\{f_m\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\|\cdot\|$. By the inequality derived, $\{f_m\}$ is Cauchy in measure with respect to $K(\cdot\times\mathbb{R}^n)$, so there exists the limit in measure $f$:
$$ B_m=\{(x,s)\in\mathbb{R}^n \times[0,T]:|f(x,s)-f_m(x,s)|\geq\epsilon\},$$
$$ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}K(B_m\times\mathbb{R}^n)=0. $$
Now I estimate $\|f_m-f\|^2$ by decomposing the integral into $B_m^c\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B_m\times\mathbb{R}^n$:
\begin{align*}
 \|f_m-f\|^2= & \iiint_{B_m^c\times\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x,t)f(y,t)|K(dx,dt,dy)+\iiint_{B_m\times\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x,t)f(y,t)|K(dx,dt,dy) \\
\leq & \epsilon \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y,t)|K(dx,dt,dy)+\|f\|_\infty^2 K(B_m\times\mathbb{R}^n).
\end{align*}
Finally, let $m\rightarrow\infty$.

The main issue is that $K(B_m\times\mathbb{R}^n)$ or $\|f\|_\infty$ may not be finite. I do not know if the $\sigma$-finite condition has some use here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a comment. The $\|\cdot\|$ is not really a norm, the triangle inequality fails. Nor do I see that it is a quasi-norm. How do you define the topology in this case?

Comment: @user284331 According to _An Introduction to Stochastic Partial Differential Equations_, by J.B.Walsh (available in google), page 290, it is a norm when $K$ is positive definite and is symmetric in $x$ and $y$. I will edit the question.